# Altera Quartus Error (12007): Top-level design entity "alt_ex_1" is undefined

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus

I've looked at all the previous questions and no one seems to have a problem
as simple as mine. Also I've searched the web and can't find a solution.

I'm new to VHDL and am trying to compile the simple example provided
by Altera, which is as follows:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity light is
port(x1, x2: in std_logic;
          f: out std_logic);
end light;

architecture LogicFunction of light is
begin
    f <= (x1 and not x2) or (not x1  and x2);
end LogicFunction;
```

I followed the project creation steps in the [Altera tutorial](ftp://ftp.intel.com/pub/fpgaup/pub/Intel_Material/9.0/Tutorials/VHDL/Quartus_II_Introduction.pdf),
but when I try to compile the project I get the error:

```
Error (12007): Top-level design entity "alt_ex_1" is undefined
```

Comment: The link to the **Altera tutorial** is broken. It seems to be [the same tutorial as this one](ftp://ftp.intel.com/pub/fpgaup/pub/Intel_Material/9.0/Tutorials/VHDL/Quartus_II_Introduction.pdf).

Comment: The term `design entity` found in the error message is defined in the VHDL standard (e.g. IEEE Std 1076-2008 3. Design entities and configurations, 3.1 General) and the meaning of top-level. "The *design entity* is the primary hardware abstraction in VHDL. It represents a portion of a hardware design that  has  well-defined  inputs  and  outputs  and  performs  a  well-defined  function.  A  design  entity  may  represent an entire system, a subsystem, a board, a chip, a macro-cell, a logic gate, or any level of abstraction in-between."

Comment: "... The top-level block in such a hierarchy is the design entity itself; such a block is an external block  that  resides  in  a  library  and  may  be  used  as  a  component  of  other  designs. ..." It helps to understand "Elaboration  of  a  design  hierarchy  defined  by  a  design  entity  consists  of  the  elaboration  of  the  block  statement equivalent to the external block defined by the design entity." (14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy). The net effect here is that the top-level design entity name is `light` and not `alt_ex_1`. You've made a typographical tool error.

Comment: An up-to-date link to the *Altera tutorial*, written out explicitly: [ftp://ftp.intel.com/pub/fpgaup/pub/Intel_Material/9.0/Tutorials/VHDL/Quartus_II_Introduction.pdf](ftp://ftp.intel.com/pub/fpgaup/pub/Intel_Material/9.0/Tutorials/VHDL/Quartus_II_Introduction.pdf).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In chapter `Starting a New Project`, you were asked to call your project `light`. It seems to me that you didn't follow that step correctly and name your project `alt_ex_1`. That's why you're getting 12007 error, since the compiler has no idea what is the top-level entity in you design.

To solve that problem you can:

1. Change the top-level entity assignment in `Assignments -> Device -> General`.
2. Set your module as top-entity via `Project Navigator` (`Files -> Set as top-level entity`).

Btw [1](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=3857), [2](http://embdev.net/topic/307733), [3](http://www.altera.com/literature/rn/archives/rn_qts_120.pdf), ... - all about the same problem.

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't fully understand the meaning of top level entity in this instance. I assumed that because I only have one file that the software would assume the first entity. I notice that I can still call my project anything I like e.g 'alt_ex_3' but I must specify the top-level design entity as 'light'. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 20):

My problem was about verilog code compiler. But when I search for problem, I always saw this question. So I decided to add my solution too to guide others. It took me much time to find solution. here is what I had done to solve the problem.Just follow these steps (Quartus II 14.0.0) ; `Assignments` -> `Settings` -> `Top-Level Entity` ->`Select your module`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if in the Select Entity window there's nothing there?

Answer (score 2):

Just put the pointer over the file name in the project navigator panel and click with right button and then push on (set as top-level entity).
Done.

Answer (score 1):

#### A Short Answer

```
Error (12007): Top-level design entity "alt_ex_1" is undefined
```

The error message is far from trivial to make sense of, but in a roundabout
way it *does* tell what is wrong.
You are (probably) using `alt_ex_1.vhd` as the name of your design file.
In Altera Quartus, the **file name** must be the same as the name of the
(top level) `entity` declared in the VHDL design code.
What you need to do is to change the file name from `alt_ex_1.vhd` to
`light.vhd`.
To keep it simple, create a new project named `light` instead of `alt_ex_1`.

#### An Elaborated Answer

Reproducing the error is straightforward. Here is what I did. <sup>1</sup>

After starting the **Quartus Prime Lite Edition** click `File` >
`New Project Wizard...`.
If you see an **Introduction**, click `Next >`. Choose a working directory.
As name of the project enter `alt_ex_1`.
Click `Next >` twice and then `Finish`.
Create a design file: `File` > `New...`.
Under `Design Files`, choose `VHDL File`, then <kbd>OK</kbd>.
Next `File` > `Save As...`. Type or paste `alt_ex_1.vhd` and click
`Save`.
Paste the code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity light is
port(x1, x2: in std_logic;
          f: out std_logic);
end light;

architecture LogicFunction of light is
begin
    f <= (x1 and not x2) or (not x1  and x2);
end LogicFunction;
```

and save the file again.

Compile with `Processing` > `Start` > `Start Analysis & Synthesis` - or  press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.
The *Message* window displays the error:

```
12007 Top-level design entity "alt_ex_1" is undefined
```

To get rid of the annoying error, delete all the files that were created in
the working directory, and then start all over.
Follow the instructions as above, but this time make sure to replace every
occurrence of `alt_ex_1` with `light`.

In the *Message* window expect to see something like:

```
Quartus Analysis & Synthesis was successful. 0 errors, 1 warning
```

as one of the last lines.

---

<sup>1</sup> Using Altera / Intel Quartus Lite 18.1 on Windows 10, but the
version is likely not important.

#### References:

- [Download Quartus Prime Lite Edition](https://fpgasoftware.intel.com/20.1.1/?edition=lite)
- [Error: top level design entity " " is undefined](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Quartus-Prime-Software/Error-top-level-design-entity-quot-quot-is-undefined/td-p/78359)
- [Quartus II Introduction Using VHDL Design](ftp://ftp.intel.com/pub/fpgaup/pub/Intel_Material/9.0/Tutorials/VHDL/Quartus_II_Introduction.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The  name of the .vhd file should be the same as the name of top-level entity, solution is simple - just
replace **light** with **alt_ex_1**