# Altera Quartus II "Error (12061): Can't synthesize current design -- Top partition does not contain any logic"

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus

I recently started working with FPGAs and have been trying to get a basic VHDL program up and running. My code is intended to take the inputs from 10 switches and map them to 10 LED outputs on my dev board, but when I attempt to run analysis/synthesis I get the error in the title. Analyzing the file individually by running "Analyze Current File" yields no errors. A similar post was made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832326/altera-quartus-error-12007-top-level-design-entity-alt-ex-1-is-undefined?newreg=929673472d19409fa6e3ebaddcdefcea), but the solution there does not help me. I have only one file in my project and I am certain that it has been specified as the top-level entity.

```
library IEEE; use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity sw_to_led is port(
    SW: in bit_vector(9 downto 0);
    LED: out bit_vector(9 downto 0));
    end sw_to_led;

architecture behavior of sw_to_led is
    begin
        LED <= SW after 5ns;
    end behavior;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Is the name of the vhdl file the same as the entity name `sw_to_led.vhd` ?
2) Are there already partitions in your design? If yes, you can try making a new Quartus-Project with the help of the "New Project Wizard" and add only the file `sw_to_led.vhd`.

By the way, `after 5ns` is not synthesizable. It should only be used in the simulation. But for Quartus it's not an error.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that the top-level file had to have the same name as the specified "top-level design entity", instead of the entity itself. I learned to read and changed the name of the actual entity to match what was specified and it fixed the issue.